# Any Optimization for unchanged data in ProtoBuf?

Tags: c#, wcf, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

Currently in my WCF based project we are facing high bandwidth usage issues. To reduce the bandwidth usage we have some internal serializer which compacts data and passes this data to wcf stack.

Example: SendData(Stream);
stream contains byte[], double?[][]

One of the optimization trick used is sending data only if changed which is done by comparing previous data with current and marking the nullable element as null if nothing changed. The elements which are null are marked in byte[]. Each element represented by a bit in byte[]. So if any one particular data in double?[][] not changed, we save around 8 bytes!

1) Is there any equivalent of above in ProtoBuf? is it out of the box?
2) Does protobuf use compression by default all the time? 
3) Suggest any other bandwidth optimization technique which can benefit me other than Compression which i am trying now!?

Really appreciate all experts opinion and suggestion!

Comment: In proto messages you can specify fields to be optional and then set their default values to whatever you like. If you do not initialize them when you build message they will be omitted and reconstructed at the receiver thus saving you bandwidth.